Angular - CSS styles are not applying to dynamic htmls nodes
I am not sure whether I am doing wrong, but I would like to see from where the issue is coming.
I have a project in Angular v18, and here is the problem statement:
I am loading some dynamic htmls from javascript and the data is coming from external JSON file.
Everything is working fine, data is loading good, component styles are loading properly all good. There is no issue here.
I have added multiple .scss individual files into abc.component.scss file through @import method.
All styles are applying properly expect to the dynamic html part.
I tried loading the dynamic html's required .scss file globally in the style.scss file and the styles are applying properly, not sure what is the issue when I load from abc.component.scss file.
Example abc.component.scss file code:
@import '../../assets/scss/helpers/variables';
@import '../../assets/scss/helpers/mixins';
@import '../../assets/scss/components/sidebar';
@import '../../assets/scss/components/title';

Within the same file:
@import '../../assets/scss/components/table';
@import '../../assets/scss/components/cards';
@import '../../assets/scss/components/users';

The @import files are applying properly except the last tree files which is for dynamic data part
Could anyone please help me on this?
I have an alternative solution, loading the last three .scss files in global.scss file but the problem is I dont want to load this css in all the pages.

It's hard to understand what exactly your problem is. But it's likely that your "dynamic HTML" is not covered by Angular's emulated view encapsulation.

Let us assume if that is the problem then how they apply properly when I add them to global styles.scss file?

I am thinking if my alternative solution works, how I can add a condition to load this file into a specific page only, in the angular.json file

Is there any condition method in the angular.json file at styles array "styles": [ {
"input": "src/abc.component.scss",
"bundleName": "abc.component" => any condition here?
},]

Because if you import styles in styles.scss they behave like global styles. This is the issue I'm 100% sure.

Emulated view encapsulation only works for HTML elements which are part of the component's template. It does not work "dynamic HTML", such as dynamically rendered elements or elements inside used components. Importing the component's style sheets in the global styles or via angular.json fixes the issue as there is no view encapsulation anymore, however it's not a good solution, as the styles will be in the bundle twice. A few options which could work for you:

Use ViewEncapsulation.None to disable the emulated view encapsulation. Note that styles may leak to other parts of your application.
Wrap styles for "dynamic HTML" in ::ng-deep.


Sure, I will give a try on this. Is there any possible way within the angular.json file at the styles array, can we add a condition that this file should load in the specified page?

No, this is exactly what the styleUrls property in the component metadata is made for.

yes true, but it is not working, going mad on this. aha

Since it's dynamic, I believe the relative imports are now invalid, so you need to add them as absolute imports /<<path>>/something.scss then it should work.
Provided you have added the assets directory to the assets array of angular.json.
@import '/assets/scss/components/table';
@import '/assets/scss/components/cards';
@import '/assets/scss/components/users';


This is what I mentioned above, if you call it in the angular.json file then it will load as global on all the pages, I don't to load this on other pages. It should load only on the specific page the way it works at the component level.

@VSathishKumar could you provide a working example on stackblitz where you replicate the issue and also explain what is not working on the stackblitz so that the same can be debugged
